# FIRST() or LAST() Aggregate Function in HIVE

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to HIVE and SPARK.

Consider I have following query in SQL.

```
select col1, col2, min(col3), first(col4) from tablename group by col1, col2
```

As I dont want to include the col4 in group by I have taken first(col4) (But I want col4 to be displayed)

1. I want to write the same query in Hive, but in hive there is no first function.

   Ref : https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-aggregate-functions
2. I want to write the same query in **Spark SQL** (Using dataframes).
   Similarly in spark aggregate functions there is no first function. (* The available aggregate methods are `avg`, `max`, `min`, `sum`, `count`. *)

Ref : org.apache.spark.sql.GroupedData

E.g. : 
`val df1 = sqlContext.sql(" select * from TABLENAME").groupBy("COL1","COL2").agg("COL3" -> "MIN", "COL4" -> "????")`

Is there any way to write the same with hive and spark ?

Comment: Can you example data from input and output ? What is your spark version ?

Comment: I have 100% used first() in hive context. Are you sure you can't use it?

Comment: @BradleyKaiser it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to include `col4` in `group by` and include it in select along with `sum()` , you need analytics functions:

```
select col1, 
       col2, 
       min(col3) over (partition by col1, col2) as min_col3,
       col4 
  from tablename;
```

See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 1):

```
select  col1
       ,col2
       ,s34.col3
       ,s34.col4 

from   (select      col1
                   ,col2
                   ,min(named_struct('col3',col3,'col4',col4)) as s34 

        from        tablename 

        group by    col1
                   ,col2
        ) t
;
```

or

```
select  col1
       ,col2
       ,s34.col1 as col3
       ,s34.col2 as col4 

from   (select      col1
                   ,col2
                   ,min(struct(col3,col4)) as s34 

        from        tablename 

        group by    col1
                   ,col2
        ) t
;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF